# arranging the appearance of a text file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text file as shown below

```
15
5
10
25
35
12
```

I would like to arrange the above numbers as shown below. How can I do this with awk or sed?

Desired output

```
15,5,10,25,35,12
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/3297613

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some versions:

```
awk '$1=$1' RS=  OFS=, file
15,5,10,25,35,12
```

```
paste -d, -s file
15,5,10,25,35,12
```

Answer (score 0):

Through sed,

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' file
15,5,10,25,35,12
```

Through awk,

```
$ awk -v RS= '{gsub(/\n/,",")}1' file
15,5,10,25,35,12
```